# Uniquely identify files

Tags: linux, file, filesystems

I'd like to index files in a local database but I do not understand how I can identified each individual file. For example if I store the file path in the database then the entry will no longer be valid if the file is moved or deleted. I imagine there is some way of uniquely identifying files no matter what happens to them but I have had no success with Google.

This will be for *nix/Linux and ext4 in particular, so please nothing specific to windows or ntfs or anything like that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to the excellent suggestion above, you might consider using the inode number property of the files, viewable in a shell with `ls -i`.

Using index.php on one of my boxes:

`ls -i`

yields

`196237 index.php`

I then rename the file using `mv index.php index1.php`, after which the same `ls -i` yields:

`196237 index1.php`

(Note the inode number is the same)

Comment: +1 learn something new everyday, didn't know you could do that. This would defiantly be smaller in the database then storing the entire path.

Comment: aha, I had a general idea that this existed but I couldn't get Google to give me anything relevant. Thankyou very much, I think this is exactly what I need.

I'm satisfied that moving and modifying the content of a file will not change its inode number. Off to find some relevant C libraries!

Comment: inode number is not enough, device id also has to be taken into account otherwise you could have collisions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1289864/246207

Answer (score 2):

Try using a hashing scheme such as `MD5`, `SHA-1`, or `SHA-2` these will allow you to match the files up by content.

Basically when you first create the index, you will hash all the files that you wish to add. This string is pretty good at telling if two files are different or the same. Then when you need to see if one of the files is already in the index, hash it and then compare the generated hash to your table of known hashes.

EDIT: As was said in the comments, it is a good idea to incorporate both data's so that way you can more accurately track changes

Comment: +1. You probably want to do something involving both filename and hashing though, not just hashing. A hashing only solution would let the system recognize the same file in a different place but prevent it from recognizing the same file after it has been edited.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I don't think hashing the files is appropriate to my needs. When I said "uniquely identifying files no matter what happens to them" I meant content changes as well, I apologize for nor being clear.

Comment: I see what you mean, the inode way is the way to go then

Answer (score 0):

If you do not consider files with same content same and only want to track moved/renamed files as same, then using its inode number will do. Otherwise you will have to hash the content.

Answer (score 0):

Only fly in the ointment with inodes is that they can be reassigned after a delete (depending on the platform) - you need to record the file creation Timestamp as well as the device id to be 100% sure. Its easier with windows and their user file attributes.